# Searching for a specific poem

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for the author (and proper wording) of a modern poem which could perhaps be considered a "Spaßgedicht"; it must be from the late 1960s or from the 1970s because it contains a reference to the Spaghetti Western ["Django"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(1966_film)) from 1966. I think it was written by a rather famous modern female author but my web search (let alone personal memory) draws a blank. What I recall of it is the following approximation (or mutilation):

```
Django reitet.
Plötzlich bleibt er stehn.
Er schaut nach rechts.
Er schaut nach links.
Was kann er tun?
Er reitet dafun.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know of the following Django poem. It may not be the right one, though. But may be the one that gave the idea.

```
Hans Carl Artmann: ein django der muss haben (1967)

ein django der muss haben 
zween stiebel um zu traben, 
ein fäustlein um zu schlagen, 
ein särglein ums zu tragen,
zween sporen an den fertzen, 
die nie ein rösslein schmerzen, 
ein feindlein ums zu schießen 
und gold zum kugeln gießen, 
dazu noch grund zur rache, 
denn das gehört zur sache, 
so eilt er texas auf 
und ab in tollem lauf. 
drum, kindlein, gib fein acht, 
wies unser django macht, 
willst sein nit feig und schwach, 
so tus ihm fleißig nach!
```

Comment: Nice poem :-). But I think it's not the one I remember.